# How to make halftone grunge like this in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, illustrator-effects

I want to learn how to make a texture in Illustrator as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: i want to learn how to make halftone effect with texture like that image,